# Reason for sending callback functions as argument

Tags: function

Callback function is a special kind of function that (pointer to function) is passed to caller function as argument.

Callback function is used in event-driven scenarios i.e., callback function is called by caller function if and only if particular event happens.

My doubt is, what is the reason for sending callback function  as (only) arguments?

Can't we call it inside the body of caller function as shown below?

> ```
> caller() 
>
> { 
>
>     .............
>     if(event) {
>         callback_function();
>     }
> }
> ```

instead of using the following

> ```
> caller(....,&callback_function) 
>
> { 
>     .............
>
> }
> ```

Where I  am thinking in wrong direction?

Comment: In this scenario, you can't have two callback functions. For example, in Javascript, Promises can have two callback functions: one for `resolve` and one for `reject`. I don't see how you'd do this in the given scenario. Also they're great if one parameter can be both a function or an configuration object, etc.

Comment: Callbacks are not only used for event driven scenarios, but considering if they were, you still wouldn't want to tie yourself to only executing one piece of logic. An example of how callbacks are useful outside of events is with algorithms, for example, if you're writing a sorting algorithm, you can allow a user to pass their own rules on how the sorting should work i.e. `sort( ..., (int a, int b) { return a > b } ) sort( ..., (int a, int b) { return a < b } sort( ..., (Vector a, Vector b) { return a.MagSqr( ) > b.MagSqr( ) }`

Comment: True, I got now, for multi-event driven scenarios first code will not work, but what if I apply parallel execution for all events inside the code1 itself (multi-threading)? @Phiter

Answer (score 1):

It can be done the way you propose, but the idea for callbacks sent as an argument to another function is to make them non-static callable objects (fitted for any purpose) instead of one implementation per use-case. Also, you don't always have access to invoke the "callback" function (called the way you intend to) due to scope restrictions.